# Search bar does not cover navigation bar iOS

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a view controller(FirstViewController) that pushes another view controller (SecondViewController) which contains a search controller. The search bar in the SecondViewController is an IBOutlet in the xib file. Now when the user taps on the search bar, it covers the navigation bar as well, which is the intended behaviour. Now I add SecondViewController as a child view controller to ThirdViewController, and the ThirdViewController is pushed by the FirstViewController. Now when the search bar is tapped, it does not cover the navigation bar. It just appears below the navigation bar.
The code for adding the child view controller is straight forward (in ThirdViewController):

```
    self.childViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:self.childViewController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:self.childViewController];
```

In FirstViewController:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.thirdViewController
                                                 animated:YES];
```

where the thirdViewController is a property in FirstViewController.

I have 2 questions:
1. What can be done to rectify the behaviour mentioned above?
2. There is some animation involved when the search bar is tapped. What if I want that the search bar stay as it is on tapping? ie, in this case it won't cover the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  in secondViewcontroller

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{

[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
CGRect rect = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;

float y = rect.origin.y-20;
searchBar.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(y ,0,0,0);
}
```